# What is $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)e^{-\left(\frac{1}{|x|} + \frac{1}{x}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x\to 0}  (1+x)e^{-\left(\frac{1}{|x|} + \frac{1}{x}\right)}$

Obviously L'hopital is inapplicable here. I guess it can be done by saying that $e^{-\infty}$ is almost zero so the limit is zero but what's the formal way of doing this?

Comment: $\frac1 {|x|}+\frac  1 x=0$ if $x<0$. What happens if $x>0$?

Comment: For a two-sided limit to exist both one sided limits must exist (and be the same).  The behaviour of $|x|$ is easy to describe on $x<0$ and on $x>0$, so you might look at the one-sided limits...

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{|x|} + \frac{1}{x} = 
\begin{cases}
   \frac{2}{x} & \mathrm{if\;} x > 0 \\
   0           & \mathrm{if\;} x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
In consequence, one has
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} (1+x)e^{-\left(\frac{1}{|x|}+\frac{1}{x}\right)} = \lim_{x\to0^+} (1+x)e^{-2/x} = 0
$$
but
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-} (1+x)e^{-\left(\frac{1}{|x|}+\frac{1}{x}\right)} = \lim_{x\to0^-} (1+x) = 1,
$$
so that the limit doesn't exist in the end.